# Word VBA Macro to comment out nested parenthesis

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have a macro as follows:

```
Sub CommentOutParenthsLocal()
'
' CommentBubble Macro
'
'
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection.Range
Set oScope = myRange.Duplicate

searchText = "\(*\)"

With myRange.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
    Do While .Execute(findText:=searchText, Forward:=True) = True
        If myRange.InRange(oScope) Then
            If Len(myRange.Text) > 4 Then
                ActiveDocument.Comments.Add myRange, myRange.Text
                myRange.Text = ""
            End If
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
 End With
End Sub
```

However, this doesn't work if I have nested parenthesis for example `This is my (nested parenthesis (document ) in full)`

It will match to the first right parenthesis not the outermost. Is there a way to write a regular expression where it matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advice, please try to use Option Explicit at the start of every Module/Class/Form.  This will prevent you from using variables that you haven't declared.

The code below will reduce

```
This is my (nested parenthesis (document ) in full)
```

To

```
This is my
```

with

```
(nested parenthesis (document ) in full)
```

added as a comment.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommentOutParenthsLocal()
'
' CommentBubble Macro
'
'
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection.Range

Dim oScope As Word.Range
Set oScope = myRange.Duplicate

Dim searchtext As String
searchtext = "\(*\)"

    With myRange.Find

        .MatchWildcards = True

        Do While .Execute(findText:=searchtext, Forward:=True) = True

            myRange.Select

            If myRange.InRange(oScope) Then

                Dim myCount As Long
                Dim myText As String
                myText = myRange.Text
                myCount = Len(myText) - Len(Replace(myText, "(", vbNullString)) - 1

                Do Until myCount = 0

                    myRange.MoveEndUntil cset:=")"
                    myRange.MoveEnd Count:=1
                    myCount = myCount - 1

                Loop

                If Len(myRange.Text) > 4 Then

                    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add myRange, myRange.Text
                    myRange.Text = ""

                End If
            Else

                Exit Do

            End If
            myRange.Start = myRange.End + 1
            myRange.End = oScope.End

        Loop

     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: OK I think there is an error in your code.  Try  'ActiveDocument.Comments.Add myRange.duplicate, myRange.Text'

Comment: For some reason it only shows up when I hit 'command+z' for undo. Not immediately -- even post your change.

Comment: It almost feels like when it collapses the range, it overwrites it.

Comment: With the addition of the .duplicate to myrange the code is working find on my pc.  In the review tab, show markup I do have to select show comments before the comments appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213799/discussion-between-user1357015-and-freeflow).

Comment: The code I posted *yesterday* already solves the problem. A key difference is in the Find expression, which excludes outer portions of nested parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With Selection
  Set Rng = .Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\([!\(]@\)"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If Not .InRange(Rng) Then Exit Do
    If Len(.Text) > 4 Then
      .Comments.Add .Range, .Text
      .Text = ""
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```